# xcode 6.0.1: crash always

Tags: xcode, crash

Installed xcode 6.0.1, now it crashes all time, with:

```
Loading a plug-in failed.

The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.
```

Reinstall, remove some some plugins from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

solved by xcode downgrading to:

- Xcode 5.11
- Command Line Tools (OS X 10.9) for Xcode - September 2014